# Laravel collection remove all keys if in any of them has value NULL

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, array-filter, laravel-collection

For some calculation i need to remove all keys in whole collection if he has in any array NULL value.

for example

```
[
'butter'=>['iron'=>5, 'magnesium'=>3.5],
'salt'=>['iron'=>2, 'magnesium'=>2],
'egg'=>['iron'=>4, 'magnesium'=>NULL]
]
```

Because one of item is empty i need new array to be like this

```
[
'butter'=>['iron'=>5],
'salt'=>['iron'=>2],
'egg'=>['iron'=>4]
]
```

I'm not sure i can accomplish this with Laravel collection, maybe there is better way with pure php.

P.S. Sorry my english is not so good

Comment: What have you tried? I could see this being accomplished with a couple `foreach` loops, first to set any `null` keys, 2nd to loop over and `unset()` said keys.

Comment: must be a collection? or it's a collection given as  result of a query? in this case, i think that the only way is using some foreach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK i make this code and this work like i want, but i think its ugly is there some better way with Laravel collection or in pure php

```
$foods=[
'butter'=>['iron'=>5, 'magnesium'=>3.5, 'calcium'=>3],
'salt'=>['iron'=>2, 'magnesium'=>2, 'calcium'=>6],
'egg'=>['iron'=>4, 'magnesium'=>NULL, 'calcium'=>5]
];

$nutrientsWithNull=[];

foreach($foods as $food)
{
    foreach($food as $key=>$value){
        if(is_null($value)&&!in_array($key, $nutrientsWithNull))
        {
            $nutrientsWithNull[]=$key;
        }
    }
}

foreach($foods as $key=>$food)
{
    foreach($nutrientsWithNull as $withNull ) {
       unset($foods[$key][$withNull]);
    }

}

print_r($foods);
```

and result is

```
$foods=[
'butter'=>['iron'=>5, 'calcium'=>3],
'salt'=>['iron'=>2, 'calcium'=>6],
'egg'=>['iron'=>4, 'calcium'=>5]
];
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your approach is reasonable but if you want to explore other solution here it is:

```
public function index()
{
    $foods = [
        'butter' => ['iron' => 5, 'magnesium' => 3.5, 'calcium' => 3],
        'salt' => ['iron' => 2, 'magnesium' => 2, 'calcium' => 6],
        'egg' => ['iron' => 4, 'magnesium' => NULL, 'calcium' => 5]
    ];
    $newFoods = $this->removeNullKeys($foods);
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($newFoods);die;
}

public function removeNullKeys(array $array): array
{
    $innerKeys = array_keys(current($array));
    $toRemove = array_reduce($innerKeys, function ($carry, $key) use ($array) {
        if (in_array(null, array_column($array, $key), true)) {
            $carry[$key] = null;
        }
        return $carry;
    }, []);

    return array_map(function ($e) use ($toRemove) {
        return array_diff_key($e, $toRemove);
    }, $array);
}
```

the result will be:

```
Array
(
    [butter] => Array
        (
            [iron] => 5
            [calcium] => 3
        )

    [salt] => Array
        (
            [iron] => 2
            [calcium] => 6
        )

    [egg] => Array
        (
            [iron] => 4
            [calcium] => 5
        )

)
```

I hope it helps.